# C# List-like instance initialization syntax

Tags: c#

In C# i can write

```
var y = new List<string>(2) { "x" , "y" };
```

to get a `List` with "x" and "y" initialized.

How do I declare a class to accept this initialization syntax?

I mean, I want to write:

```
var y = new MyClass(2, 3) { "x" , "y" };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at section 7.6.10.3 of the C# spec:

> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied
>   must be of a type that implements System.Collections.IEnumerable or a
>   compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the
>   collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object with
>   the expression list of the element initializer as argument list,
>   applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, the
>   collection object must contain an applicable Add method for each
>   element initializer.

A very simple example of this:

```
   class AddIt : IEnumerable
   {
      public void Add(String foo) { Console.WriteLine(foo); }

      public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
      {
         return null; // in reality something else
      }
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var a = new AddIt() { "hello", "world" };

         Console.Read();
      }
   }
```

This will print "hello", followed by "world" to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what (2,3) are supposed to indicate.  I understand that it's your collection size in the first line.  You can simply inherit from List or whatever structure you're needing to imitate.

Just tested this sample in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new Foo{
        "a",
        "b"
    };

    list.Dump();
}

class Foo : List<string>{ }
```

Comment: And why does that work?  It works because you only need to have an `Add` method that matches the items in the collection initializer, and `List` has an `Add` method.

Comment: Right. I was going for the simple answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the fields of the class using the syntax:

```
// ...

Car myCar1 = new Car () { Model = "Honda", YearBuilt=2009 };
Car myCar2 = new Car () { Model = "Toyota", YearBuilt=2011 };

// ...

public class Car {

    public string Model;
    public int YearBuilt;
}
```

Comment: While it isn't exactly what was asked, it may well be useful to know about object initialization.

Comment: Object initialization is entirely different from collection initialization.  While the syntax is similar, the concept and implementation is entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

As Marcus points out, the class must implement the `IEnumerable` interface and have an `Add()` method accessible to the caller.

In short, this skeleton example will work:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(string item)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```